# Hidden Variable in JavaScript, how does this work?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some clarification as to what is happening in this example scenario:

There is a parameter being passed into a URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/page/?param=test
```

When I look at the source of this page I see this:

```
function myfunction() {
            myvariable.append('test');
          }
```

The value of the parameter is already hard coded into the snippet.

How can this happen? I don't ever see the parameter being grabbed or used.

Comment: That javascript doesn't look right: I don't think that will parse. Are you sure that's the correct script?  Also, what does `myvariable` have as content at the point that `myfunction()` is called?

Comment: I edited it, sorry i didn't notice the mistake I left in. At the point the function is called myvariable is assigned via jQuery a <div> element via id selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see it being processed in the client, then the only other (reasonable) option remains: it's grabbed & templated on the server.

Comment: I figured as much, but I'm looking for some more detail on what types of techniques can be used to accomplish this.

Comment: Server-side templating/programming of pretty much any nature. There are a bajillion languages out there, each with a gazillion libraries and frameworks, for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible that the page is using both the GET and the POST methods. As it retreives the POSTed variable it can process it in PHP and display it right into the javascript.